# Sandbox Connection refused via Ambari and Putty

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, putty, ambari

I had an unfortunate PC shutdown while using sandbox. Since than I can use sandbox with all hadoop technologies but cannot use any of the ports reserved it seems. While trying to connect to Ambari and to sandbox via Putty I am getting Connection refused.

I've followed various steps in provided in other questions within various forums but nothing seemed to work.

[Connection refused via Ambari and Putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmHFM.png)

Comment: Which sandbox version are you using? Have you forwarded the ports in your VM settings?

Comment: sandbox version is 2.4 and yes ports have been forwarded (ambari: 8080 and ssh: 2222)... the problem is that while i was working there was a power shortage and pc turned off...after that i was not able to connect to either ambari and ssh(putty)

Comment: Can you log in on the VM console at all?

Comment: yes sandbox is operable...just via sandbox...it's not accessible through any ambari and ssh

Comment: Is sshd and ambari-server up and running in the sandbox? You could check by accessing the sandbox by VM console and running: `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080` and `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 2222`. If neither or those produce output then those services are not running and listening on those respective ports.